# increasing and decreasing functions with functional equations

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f'(\sin x)<0$ and $f''(\sin x)>0$ for all $x$ between $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $g(x)=f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)$, then find the set of values of $x$ for which $g(x)$ is decreasing between $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

I figured out the first derivative of $g(x)$ and got that $g(x)$ is decreasing in the whole domain.
Can someone tell me whether my answer is right or wrong.

Comment: If you haven't used the information on $f''(\sin x)$ then either you have made a mistake or the person who wrote the problem included unnecessary information.

Comment: What did you get for the derivative of $g(x)$?  How did you determine that $g(x)$ is decreasing in the whole domain without knowing $f'(\cos x)$?